# Norm of a polynomial $N_{E/K}(f)(X)$ with $E/K$ a Galois extension

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

I am quite new to Galois Theory and tried to give a go at this exercise:

Let $E/K$ be a finite Galois extension with $G=\text{Gal}(E/K)$. For each polynomial $f(X)\in E[X]$ we define:
$$N_{E/K}(f)(X)=\prod_{\sigma \in G} f^{\sigma}(X)$$

1. Check that $N_{E/K}(f)(X) \in K[X]$.
2. Prove that if $N_{E/K}(f)(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$, then $f(X)$ is irreducible in $E[X]$. Is the converse true?
3. Prove that if $N_{E/K}(f)(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$ then the coefficients of $f$ generate $E$ over $K$.
4. Let $f(X)\in E[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial and let $\alpha$ be a root of this polynomial in an algebraic closure $\bar{E}$. Prove that the normal closure of the extension $E(\alpha)/K$ in $\bar{E}$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $N_{E/K}(f)(X)$.

I thought I understood the theory, but I don't know where to begin. For (1), I'd like to see that the coefficients of the polynomial are in $K$, but how do I continue? I know $\sigma$ fixes $K$ but $f(X)\in E(X)$. For the others, I lay the definitions and try to go for a contradiction but nothing comes from it.

I've looked all over the reference books and the internet and can only find similar definitions [regarding elements of $E$](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm2.pdf), not polynomials. Any help, indications or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of $\sigma(f(X))$ here? Are we saying that $N_{E/K}(f)$ is the function given by $X \mapsto \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(f(X))$, and our goal is to check that this function is given by a polynomial with coefficients in $K$? It'd be nice if $X \mapsto \sigma(f(X))$ was given by a polynomial with coefficients in $E$, but this is not the case; e.g. take $\sigma$ to be conjugation with $E/K = \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$, and note that $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is not a polynomial map.

Comment: $\sigma(f(X))$ means applying $\sigma$ to the coefficients, usually denoted $f^\sigma(X)$, and the subring of $E[X]$ fixed by $Gal(E/K)$ is $K[X]$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks -- I was pretty confused by this notation. The function being written as $\sigma(f(X))$ is actually $\sigma \circ f \circ \sigma^{-1}$!

Comment: You should say $f(X)$ is in $E[X]$, not $E(X)$.  And you looked in the wrong handout I posted: see Theorem 3.3 and Corollary 3.5 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisappn.pdf for related ideas.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk sorry if the notation was confusing. I'll edit now

Comment: See Theorem 2.9 and 2.11 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrthms.pdf for more related results, this time involving multivariable polynomials.

Comment: @KCd that's correct, I messed the parentheses. I'll edit it now. Also thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\sigma(f(X))$ means applying $\sigma$ to the coefficients, usually denoted $f^\sigma(X)$ (well KCd prefers the notation $(\sigma f)(X)$) and the subring of $E[X]$ fixed by $Gal(E/K)$ is $K[X]$.
2. is obvious
3. for $E/F/K$ then $F=E$ iff $F$ is not fixed by any $\sigma$.
4. the roots of $f^\sigma$ are $K$-conjugates to the roots of $f$.

Comment: 1. from this I gent that if $f(X) \in K[X]$ then $f^\sigma(X) \in K[X]$, the hypothesis is $f(X) \in E[X]$ My apologies being so obtuse.

2. Is this obvious because $E/K$ is separable? I'm trying to use this but I can't seem to find the way.