If $L/K$ is an extension, then how to get an irreducible factor of $f(x)$ in $K[x]$, when an irreducible factor of it is given in $L[x]$?
I am working on the following lemma:
If $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial in $K[x]$ with no repeated factors of degree greater than $1$, then $L$ is a finite algebraic extension of $K$, and that $g(x)$ is monic, irreducible, polynomial in $L[x]$ of degree $\geq 1$, which divides $f(x)$. Put $h(x) = \textrm{Norm}_{L/K} g(x)$(For definition of this norm you can see this post). Then

$\gcd(f(x),h(x))$ is an irreducible factor of degree $\geq 1$ of $f(x)$ in $K[x]$ in $K[x]$;

If the field extension $L/K$ is generated by the coefficients of $g(x)$, then $h(x)$ is already an irreducible factor of $f(x)$ in $K[X]$.


I am reading a paper, where this Lemma 2.9 was stated, with no proof or reference.
I know a theorem that states that:
Theorem: If $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension and if $g(x)$ is an irreducible factor of $f(x)$ in $L[x]$ then the polynomial $h(x)$ is in $K[x]$ and and irreducible there.
So I think the 1st part of the Lemma which I stated actually holds for the general case, I mean when $L/K$ is not a Galois extension.
The 2nd part of the lemma is I think the Galois extension case. But I am not sure about that, if the field extension $L/K$ is generated by the coefficients of $g(x)$, then $L/K$ is a Galois extension.
Is it the correct intuition? or am I doing something wrong? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Can you provide us with a link to the paper?

Sure I updated that. Lemma 2.9 of the paper

In the paper $f$ is said to have no repeated factors of degree $\ge 1$, not greater than 1. And how is the norm of a polynomial defined? I only know the norm of an element of some field

They haven't defined it, but I guess that is multiplication of all conjugate factors

The definition of the norm can be found in the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3939461/norm-of-a-polynomial-n-e-kfx-with-e-k-a-galois-extension

As stated, this is wrong. Consider $K=\mathbb Q$, $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$, $f=X^3-2$ and $g=X-\sqrt[3]2$. Then $\operatorname{Aut}_K(L)=\{\operatorname{id}\}$, so the linked definition of the norm would give $N_{L/K}g=g\notin K[X]$. In fact one needs $L^{\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)}=K$ to prove $N_{L/K}g\in K[X]$. So I will assume from now on that $L/K$ is Galois. In characteristic $0$, this isn't too bad: Simply pass from $L$ to its normal closure. I'm not sure if anything can be done in the non-separable case. If there is a more general definition for the norm of a polynomial, let me know and I'll see if the proof can be generalized.

Let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$. Then by definition $N_{L/K}g=\prod_{\sigma\in G}g^\sigma$. Let $\sigma\in G$. Since we know that $g\mid f$, also $g^\sigma\mid f$. This should be clear intuitively, since $K$ "doesn't see" the action of $\sigma$. Formally, if $f=gk$, then $$f=f^\sigma=(gk)^\sigma=g^\sigma k^\sigma.$$ By the same token, $g^\sigma$ is irreducible, since $g$ is. We now have a bunch of irreducible polynomials that divide $f$, and would like to conclude that their product does as well.
This is almost true: It holds if all the $g^\sigma$ are non-associated (that's an easy fact about prime elements in general). If the coefficients of $g$ generate $L/K$, this holds, since any $\sigma\neq 1$ must change some coefficient of $g$. So, under this assumption, we can conclude $N_{L/K}g\mid f$. Also, $N_{L/K}g$ is irreducible in this case:
Suppose $N_{L/K}g=g_1g_2$. Since $g$ divides $g_1g_2$ and is irreducible, it divides one of the factors, say $g_1$. But then by the same argument as above, $g^\sigma\mid g_1$ for every $\sigma\in G$, and thus $N_{L/K}g\mid g_1$. Hence $g_2$ is a unit and we have completed the proof of part 2.

Now we move to the general case. It's certainly not true in general that $N_{L/K}\mid f$, take for example $K=\mathbb Q$, $L=\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt2)$, $f=X^2+1$ and $g=X-i$. Then $N_{L/K}g=(X-i)^2(X+i)^2=f^2$.
But certainly $k:=\gcd(f,N_{L/K}g)\mid f$. Furthermore, $k$ can't be trivial: The gcd is independent of the field it is computed in (by correctness of the Euclidean Algorithm), and $g\mid f,N_{L/K}g$ in $L$. It remains to show that $k$ is irreducible.
For this we need the condition that $f$ has no repeated roots (in an algebraic closure of $K$, say). Let $f=\prod f_i$ be the facorization of $f$ into irreducible elements $f_i\in K[X]$. Now we can conclude that $g$, and hence all $g^\sigma$ divide exactly one of the $f_i$. Indeed, if $g\mid f_i,f_j$, then a root of $g$ in $\overline K$ is a root of both $f_i$ and $f_j$, hence a double root of $f$. This finishes the proof.

Note that the theorem you quote at the end of your post doesn't hold, as my example above shows. For $N_{L/K}g$ to be irreducible, you really need the condition that the coefficients of $g$ generate $L/K$.

Just to be clear: Does the extension $L/K$ needs to be normal for what you are writing?

Actually, yes! None of my arguments rely on it (that's why I forgot it), but $L/K$ needs to be Galois for the norm of polynomials to be well-defined (afaik). See edit.

Thanks for answering. I have one doubt. Actually I wrote the last theorem from a pdf https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrthms.pdf. Theorem 2.11.

Note that in the pdf, Conrad talks about the product of all different $\sigma(\pi)$, while the norm takes all of them, including repeats. You can see that in the example: The norm yields $f^2$, because each factor occurs twice. Remove duplicates and you get $f$ back and everything works.

Yes that is the confusion then. What is the standard definition of norm then. I mean in the paper it was not given so I searched and got a link which talk about the norm, so I attached it. As per my understanding if we use different $\sigma(\pi)$ as the definition of norm then can we say that for G the result is true. Or we need L/K to be a Galois extension?

In the answer you are also using $G = Gal(L/K)$, but the lemma which I started have no such assumption. So can you tell me whether I am missing something? Actually I am not familiar with Galois theory. Read some basic things, don't know each result. So may be I couldn't able to see the basics things.

The only definition of the norm of a polynomial I am aware of (the one you linked) is $N(f)=\prod_{\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal(L/K)}}f^\sigma$, which only works if $L/K$ is Galois, see the first paragraph of my answer. Maybe you can ask a separate question about how to define such a norm in the non-Galois case.

Ok I got it. I will ask that.

The solution of @anankElpis is fine, but I am writing this with slight modifications. It will be a great help if you can check whether everything is fine or not. What I add to it is that the $\gcd(f(X),h(X)) = d(X)$, where $d(X)$ is the product of all distinct values of $\sigma(g(X))$, which I defined below.

We assume that $L/K$ is a Galois extension and $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$.
By the definition we have $h(X) = \mathrm{Norm}_{L/K} g(X)$. As we know $g(X)$ is a monic irreducible factor of $f(X)$ in $L[X]$. We can assume that, $f(X) = g(X)k(X)$, then $$\sigma(f(X)) = f(X) = \sigma(g(X)k(X)) = \sigma(g(X)) \sigma(k(X)).$$ First of all, we have to observe that if $g(X)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $L[X]$, then $\sigma(g(X))$ is also an irreducible polynomial in $L[X]$, if not then we can write $$\sigma(g(X)) = a(X)b(X) \implies g(X) = \sigma^{-1}(a(X)b(X)) = \sigma^{-1}(a(X)) \sigma^{-1}(b(X)),$$ which contradicts the fact that $g(X)$ is irreducible. So we have a bunch of irreducible factors of $f(X)$. So $h(X)$ is also a factor of $f(X)$ in $L[X]$.

Part (a):$~~$  For $\sigma \in G$, we have $\sigma(\sigma_{i}(g(X))) = (\sigma\sigma_{i})(g(X))$, where $\sigma_i \in G$. Let the distinct elements of $\{\sigma(g(X)) : \sigma \in G\}$ be listed as $\{\sigma_1(g(X)), \sigma_2(g(X)), \cdots, \sigma_m(g(X))\}$.
Let, $$d(X) = \displaystyle \prod_{i = 1}^{m} \sigma_{i}(g(X)) \in K[X].$$
We will prove that this $d(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$. If possible let $b(X)$ be a non-constant factor of $d(X)$ in $K[X]$. We know that $d(X)$ is a decomposition of irreducible factors in $L[X]$, so one of them must be a factor of $b(X)$, say $\sigma_i(g(X)) \mid b(X)$ in $L[X]$, which implies $\sigma(\sigma_i(g(X))) \mid \sigma(b(X)) \iff \sigma(\sigma_i(g(X))) \mid b(X)$ in $L[X]$, as $b(X) \in K[X]$. Since $\sigma$ acts as a permutation on the set $\{\sigma_1(g(X)), \sigma_2(g(X)), \cdots, \sigma_m(g(X))\}$, so we have, $\sigma_i(g(X)) \mid b(X)$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$. As $\sigma_i(g(X))$ are not scalar multiples of each other in $L[X]$, so $b(X)$ is divisible by the product of all of them, hence $d(X) \mid b(X)$ hence $d(X) = b(X)$, so $d(X)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[X]$.
Now if we assume $b(X) = \gcd(f(X), h(X))$ then $b(X) \mid f(X)$, and $b(X)$ can't be trivial as $g(X) \mid f(X)$ and $g(X) \mid h(X)$. To prove the lemma we have to show that $b(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$. First of all, observe that $d(X) \mid h(X)$, where we already showed that $d(X)$ is an irreducible factor of $f(X)$ in $K[X]$.
Here we need the condition that $f(X)$ has no repeated factors of degree $\geq 1$. Let $f(X) = \displaystyle \prod f_i(X)$ be the factorization of $f(X)$ into irreducible elements $f_i(X) \in K[X]$. Now as $d(X)$ is also an irreducible factor of $f(X)$ in $K[X]$, hence we can conclude that $d(X)$, divide exactly one of the $f_i(X)$ in $K[X]$. Indeed, if $d(X) \mid f_i(X) ~\&~ d(X) \mid f_j(X)$ in $K[X]$, then $(d(X))^2$ is a factor of both $f_i(X)$ and $f_j(X)$ in $K[X]$, hence $f(X)$ has
a repeated factor of degree $\geq 1$. This is a contradiction. So let  $d(X) \mid f_i(X)$, for some $i$. Now $d(X) \mid f_i(X) \mid f(X)$ in $K[X]$ and also $d(X) \mid h(X) \implies 
d(X) \mid \gcd(f(X),h(X))$. As $d(X)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[X]$, hence $\gcd(f(X),h(X)) = d(X)$. Hence $\gcd(f(X), h(X))$ is an irreducible factor of degree $\geq 1$ of $f(X)$ in $K[X]$.

Part (b): Now it is given that coefficients of $g(X)$ generate the field extension $L/K$. Then any non-trivial $\sigma$ changes some coefficient of $g(X)$. Here we can claim that if $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are two distinct element of $G$, then $\sigma_1(g(X))$ and $\sigma_2(g(X))$ are also different: If $$\sigma_1(g(X)) = \sigma_2(g(X)) \implies \sigma_{1}^{-1}\sigma_{2}(g(X)) = g(X),$$ so $\sigma_{1}^{-1}\sigma_{2}$, fixes all the coefficients of $g(X)$ and therefore $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$. Here $h(X) = d(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$.
